# Add new row to table 3

Tags: jquery

This is my table, i would like help:

I need to add a new row to table 3, for my project im doing. Help would be very much appreciated. I put a snippet down below so you guys can see the live run of the code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".selectit").click(function(){
            
            //add code here
            alert($(this).text());
            $(".fes-variations-list-multiple").append('<tr class="fes-single-variation">
                <td class="fes-name-row">
                    <input class="fes-name-value" name="option[1][description]" id="option[1][description]" rows="3" value="" type="text">
                </td>
                <td class="fes-price-row">
                    <input class="fes-price-value" name="option[1][price]" id="option[1][price]" value="0" type="text">
                </td>
                <td class="fes-delete-row">
                    <a href="#" class="edd-fes-delete">
                        ×
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>');
            
            
            
            
            
            //end code
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="multiple">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="fes-name-column">Chủng loại hàng hóa</th>
                    <th class="fes-price-column">Số tiền ( VND)</th>
                    <th class="fes-remove-column">&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="fes-variations-list-multiple">
                <tr class="fes-single-variation">
                    <td class="fes-name-row">
                        <input class="fes-name-value" name="option[0][description]" id="options[0][description]" rows="3" value="" type="text">
                    </td>
                    <td class="fes-price-row">
                        <input class="fes-price-value" name="option[0][price]" id="options[0][price]" value="0" type="text">
                    </td>
                    <td class="fes-delete-row">
                        <a href="#" class="edd-fes-delete">
                            ×
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="5">
                        <a href="#" class="edd-submit button insert-file-row" id="multiple">Thêm</a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

But it does not work. Could anybody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript doesn't accept multi line strings. Change your append code into that:

```
$(".fes-variations-list-multiple").append('<tr class="fes-single-variation">'
        +'<td class="fes-name-row">'
        +'<input class="fes-name-value" name="option[1][description]" id="option[1][description]" rows="3" value="" type="text">'
        +'</td>'
        +'<td class="fes-price-row">'
        +'<input class="fes-price-value" name="option[1][price]" id="option[1][price]" value="0" type="text">'
        +'</td>'
        +'<td class="fes-delete-row">'
        +'<a href="#" class="edd-fes-delete">'
        +'×'
        +'</a>'
        +'</td>'
        +'</tr>');
```

Comment: thanks. you are right. My next step is to add many rows, and i want option[1] to increase to option[2], option[3]... Can you suggest how to do it?

Comment: Just use a `for` loop, then use the counter as a value for the input number

Answer (score 0):

Your code will fail if there is no row in table. Instead of directly appending a row in table append it to your `tbody` element.

```
$('.fes-variations-list-multiple').find('tbody:last').append('<tr class="fes-single-variation">'
    +'<td class="fes-name-row">'
    +'<input class="fes-name-value" name="option[1][description]" id="option[1][description]" rows="3" value="" type="text">'
    +'</td>'
    +'<td class="fes-price-row">'
    +'<input class="fes-price-value" name="option[1][price]" id="option[1][price]" value="0" type="text">'
    +'</td>'
    +'<td class="fes-delete-row">'
    +'<a href="#" class="edd-fes-delete">'
    +'×'
    +'</a>'
    +'</td>'
    +'</tr>');
```